# Updating overlay on Google Maps API idle event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the maps "idle" event handler, I'm getting some location data (coordinates, etc.) from another API's call and placing those coordinates on an overlay. When the map first loads, everything looks fine. But after the initial load, when I drag the map, get more data, then put the new data on the map, the new data is offset. After dragging again, the data fetched after the last drag is positioned, correctly, but the new data isn't.

It seems like positioning this new data doesn't take the map's new bounds into account. I also notice that the event executes my code to fetch and draw new data asynchronously. Could this be related?

Comment: you're probably loading data on start of the drag (old bounds).

Comment: @elrado, I'm loading the data on the idle event, which I believe has the new bounds. On idle, I get the new center of the map, load data within a certain radius around that center, then populate the map. I add markers for those places, which show in the right spot. And I also update a heat map, which doesn't show in the right spot.

Comment: Do you have a link to your implementation?

Comment: Sure. It's officially launched, but with no SEO, marketing or advertising. So it's on a live site. I'm considering just pulling the heat map out altogether. But you'll need a Foursquare account to access the data. [http://www.gravatonic.com/](http://www.gravatonic.com/)

Comment: Oh, and if no points show up, it's because there's no data for your current location. Scroll the map to a nearby big city.

Comment: Well, I'd have a look, but having read the Privacy Policy, I'm not signing up with Foursquare.